# Cannot access before initialization in a vanilla Vite TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, inheritance, vite

I have a vanilla TypeScript project with Vite. I am using `import` and `export` without any errors in the `console`, but when running the project, there is an error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Mark' before initialization
    at /src/ts/BlueMark.ts?t=1703626680866:2:31
```

I am using inheritance, I have a Mark class which is the parent class of all "marks", and then I have child classes.

`export class BlueMark extends Mark`

I have [a CodeSandbox item with an example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/test-import-kjy2nc?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.ts%3A15%2C2) (the minimal code was added to reproduce the error).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77723503/edit). Thanks in advance.